# Spring boot, Non-parseable POM

Tags: java, spring, maven

soy nuevo en spring boot y tengo una pregunta. Cuando inicio un nuevo proyecto de tipo maven, en "Spring tool suite", me encuentro con este error en mi `POM.xml`

> "1 problem was encountered while building the effective model [FATAL]
>   Non-parseable POM
>   C:\Users\micha.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-surefire-plugin\2.21.0\maven-surefire-plugin-2.21.0.pom:
>   only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not \u0
>   (position: START_DOCUMENT seen \u0... @1:1)  @ line 1, column 1"

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Comment: Tal vez no esta cerrada correctamente una etiqueta dentro del pom.xml, revisa si tiene un caracter raro por ahí.

Comment: ¿Puedes copiar tu pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

El error lo tienes en esta dependencia Maven: maven-surefire-plugin-2.21.0.pom,

Busca C:\Users\micha.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-surefire-plugin\2.21.0\maven-surefire-plugin-2.21.0.pom

Abre el .pom y busca/elimina cualquier carácter que tenga al principio de linea del documento (se queja de que encuentra `\u0` creo que es un ".") pero puede ser cualquier cosa.

El pom debería empezar el fichero con `<project>`

Esto debería solucionarte el problema.

Comment: Esta solución seguirá dando problemas en caso de intentar construir el proyecto en otro equipo.

Comment: Suponiendo que sea un problema en el pom de la dependencia, tendrá que corregir el error en el repositorio correspondiente o reportarlo como un incidencia si es un repositorio como Maven Central ya que como dices @pablo simpre tendrá este problema cuando no utilice el repositorio local de su pc. Pero lo primero es identificar que sea este el problema que tiene ya que mi respuesta está basada solo en el log que pone, ahora hace falta más información.

Comment: Es más un comentario que una respuesta por esas razones.